# How to install indicator-cpufreq on fedora 22?

Tags: fedora, gnome, burning

I'm new on Fedora and I would like to know how to install the little applet named "indicator-cpufreq" on my Fedora laptop cause my i7 4700HQ burn over 90°C after few seconds when the average cpu charge is over 80%. I just would like to lower the CPU frequency to limit the temperature.

For information, I already tried `dnf install indicator-cpufreq` but that didn't find the package and i don't find any help on other forums, do I need to add sources? How can I do that on Fedora?

Comment: You can try Gnome extension for that:
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1082/cpufreq/

Answer (score -1):

try dnf/yum search these packages:

- CPUFreqUtility
- cpufreq
- kernel-tools